# What's the usage of ReactiveObject.ThrownExceptions?

Tags: reactiveui

I have searched a lot of related information, but I can't find any sample of the usage of `ReactiveObject.ThrownExceptions`.

I have wrote some codes to raise exception on the ViewModel, and subscribe the `ThrownExceptions` property of `ViewModel` (inherits from `ReactiveObject`), but it can't catch any exception at all.

Can someone tell me what's the right usage of `ReactiveObject.ThrownExceptions` property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should mostly ignore it, it should probably be removed off of ReactiveObject - it's solely a Footgun at this point.